# Mishna Berura Ruling on Tying Tekhelet

Tags: sources-mekorot, mishnah-berurah, techeles

Does the Mishna Berura rule on the way to tie Tekhelet and the number of Tekhelet strings to use?  If so, could you please provide a citation and quote/translation?  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mishnah Berurah 9:7 mentions 2 strings of white and 2 strings of techeles this is the opinion of many rishonim(Rashi,Tosfos, Rosh,Itur,etc...).

ז(ז) בזמן הזה - פי' דבזמן שהיה תכלת שהיה צריך להטיל ד' חוטין שני חוטי לבן ושני חוטי תכלת (הוא צמר צבוע בדם חלזון) והיה מתקיים עי"ז המצות ציצית כראוי התירה לנו התורה להטיל השנים של לבן בין מצמר או מפשתים בין בבגד צמר או בבגד פשתים ולהי"א שזכר רמ"א בס"א דכל מיני בגדים חייבין מדאורייתא אפילו בהם היה אז מותר לנו מן התורה ציצית של צמר ופשתים יחדיו אבל עכשיו דאין לנו תכלת נמצא דאין אנו מקיימין המצוה בשלמותה לא שרי לן כלאים:

A list of those who hold 2 of white and 2 of techeiles(A list I compiled a while ago):

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!  I wonder why so many Ashkenazim that have Tekhelet don’t go with Tosofot and instead use the Vilna Goan or Rambam.

Comment: Well Rav Belsky wore 2 and 2. Rav Hershel Shachter wears 2 and 2 as well. The Gra mentions all 3 shittos (half,1,and 2),but in his halachic work Biur Hagra he mentions 2 and 2. It seems that talmidei chachmim who went through sugya and are ashkanaz do in fact wear 2 and 2 .

Comment: Interesting, I thought that the Gra way of tying tekhelet was only 1 tekhelet and 3 white.

Comment: @Akiva___ It is. The Beiur HaGra is just discussing the implied opinion of the Shulchan Arukh. These lists are misleading since most of these people are just copying someone else. To say "talmidei chachmim who went through sugya and are ashkanaz do in fact wear 2" is quite the overstatement. It's more like: a lot of late rabbis who didn't even try to paskin this at-the-time-irrelevant issue copied the opinion of someone famous they'd read without thinking about it, and then some modern rabbis decided we must follow Mishna Berura because that's what they know how to say.

Comment: @Akiva___ The Gra decided that the Tannaitic material (sifra and zohar) supports 1 blue 3 white and thus ruled that way, deciding the girsa of 2/2 was mistaken. (And he's probably right.) That's how you have to approach a sugya that hasn't been live in 2000 years if you want to make a Psak (capital P)

Comment: @Akiva___ To be fair sam probably disagrees with what I said. But, hey, that's Judaism for you

Comment: @Akiva___ - I can tell you why I did. I am not sure enough that murex is the chilazon to risk fulfilling lavan in the usual Ashkenazi minhag. If I wear Rambam strings, I know my only string that isn't white / matching the garment is definitely one that is being worn to round out the count of 8 rather than  being worn as lavan. I doubt this is the popular reason, though.

Comment: @sam: For what it's worth, in Collected Writings III, R SR Hirsch assumes 1 of 8. And then waxes poetic about techeiles representing beyond nature (the color closest to the sky) just as does 8 (beyond the 7 of the week, 8 days for a beris, Shemini Atzeres, etc...). I say FWIW, because it's not really a halachic work, like if RSRH has said something similar in Horeb or a teshuvah.

Comment: It seems like I missed some comments here,just to address @doubleaa, I will start off by saying I will agree to disagree.  To say that the Rishonim just randomly picked Rashi and Tosfos shitta doesnt make sense ,since the Raavads position makes the most sense from the lashon or ptil,but that aside many of the sources I quote mention 2 and 2 like it's their position as well. With regards to the Gra I dont believe anyone truly knows his shitta since he mentions diff things in diff places. Hard to debate this in a text setting. Anyhow I rem seeing Rav Mazuz holds any shitta is fine .

Comment: @sam ya, i phrased it a bit strongly there just to counter your claim, but the principle holds more like the siyata dishmaya idea at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18767/759 and of course horyot 2a מותרים אתם לעשות

Comment: You forgot to add the Aruch HaShulchan and the Alter Rebbe's Shulchan Aruch